# Connection to Host Lost

Tags: .net, wcf, service, host

I have a service that I am hosting locally. I created a WCF project and create another console app to host it. And then I installed the host locally. I can see my service listed under computer->manage->services. (status = started)

Since the other service calling my service complained saying (Unable to SEND Message to "My service" No more attempts left). I tried to telent the service IP and Port.

I tried Telenet> o 
 my ip and port
connection to host lost...

What are the possible caused to the above error. Even though my service is up and running.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Wish I had a crystall ball.

Comment: do you have source for server, if yes I would start by trying to break into 'start' method of service initialization - its possible that service may be started, but incorrectly swallowing some exceptions before initializing web api at the expected port?

Comment: @Dreamer I am new to WCF and can you point me to a resource how to do what you suggested ?